# Setting up optimization problem in GEKKO

Tags: python, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming, constraints, gekko

I have the following dynamical system,

$\frac{d \phi}{dt} = -M^TDM\phi \tag{1}\label{1}$

$\frac{d \hat\phi}{dt} = -M^T\tilde{D}M\hat \phi \tag{2} \label{2}$

$\eqref{1}$ represents the exact dynamics of a system and $\eqref{2}$ is the approximate dynamics that should give the same time course profiles as $\eqref{1}$, after optimization. Ideally, I am solving for the dynamics of the same system in $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$. $\eqref{2}$ is more like a perturbed version of $\eqref{1}$. The perturbation is done by setting $\hat{D}$ = D/10. And for the sake of understanding, let us assume $\eqref{1}$ gives experimental values and $\eqref{2}$ are the predicted values.

The objective function includes a cost function that minimizes the difference between state variables   $\phi$ and $\hat{\phi}$, by optimizing parameter $\tilde{D}$ which are the control variables.

I'm trying to solve this as a parameter estimation problem with non-linear equality constraints/defects obtained by discretizing $\eqref{2}$ at collocation points.

In MATLAB my objective function looks like the following

```
[Dhat,~,~,output] = fmincon(@objfun,Dhat0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@defects, opts_fmin)

function f = objfun(Dhat)

%% Integrator settings
phi0    = [5; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
tspan   = 0:dt:0.5;
options = odeset('abstol', 1e-10, 'reltol', 1e-9);

%% generate exact solution
    [t, phi]  = ode15s(@(t,phi) actual(t,phi), tspan , phi0 ,options);


%% generate approximate solution

    [t, phi_tilde]  = ode15s(@(t,phi_tilde) model(t,phi_tilde, Dhat), tspan , phi0 ,options);


%% objective function for fminunc/fmincon
      f = sum((phi(:) - phi_tilde(:)).^2);
end
```

I've tried to set up the same problem in GEKKO. But I am not sure how to set up the objective function. `[t, phi]  = ode15s(@(t,phi) actual(t,phi), tspan , phi0 ,options);` in MATLAB computes the time-course profiles of `phi`. In python code, the differential equations in function `def actual():` is solved using odeint from scipy in line 102. Similarly, `[t, phi_tilde]  = ode15s(@(t,phi_tilde) model(t,phi_tilde, Dhat), tspan , phi0 ,options);` computes the time-course profiles of `phi_hat`. In GEKKO, the equations of `model` has been set up in function `def model():`.

I'm stuck at this point. It's not clear to me how `model` that has the control variables in 1d array
`Dhat` has to be set up and solved to compute the squared-error in loss function defined in objective function `f = sum((phi(:) - phi_tilde(:)).^2);(MATLAB)`.

```
# Copyright 2020, Natasha, All rights reserved.
import numpy as np

from gekko import GEKKO
from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def get_mmt():
    """
    M and M transpose required for differential equations
    :params: None
    :return: M transpose and M -- 2D arrays ~ matrices
    """
    MT = np.array([[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

    M = np.transpose(MT)
    return M, MT


def actual(phi, t):
    """
    Actual system/ Experimental measures
    :param  phi: 1D array
    :return: time course of variable phi -- 2D arrays ~ matrices
    """

    # spatial nodes
    ngrid = 10
    end = -1
    M, MT = get_mmt()
    D = 5000*np.ones(ngrid-1)
    A = MT@np.diag(D)@M
    A = A[1:ngrid-1]

    # differential equations
    dphi = np.zeros(ngrid)
    # first node
    dphi[0] = 0

    # interior nodes
    dphi[1:end] = -A@phi  # value at interior nodes

    # terminal node
    dphi[end] = D[end]*2*(phi[end-1] - phi[end])

    return dphi


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ref: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/PartialDifferentialEquations
    ngrid = 10  # spatial discretization
    end = -1

    # integrator settings (for ode solver)
    tf = 0.5
    nt = int(tf / 0.01) + 1
    tm = np.linspace(0, tf, nt)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # measurements
    # ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOzjeBaNfgo
    # using odeint to solve the differential equations of the actual system
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    phi_0 = np.array([5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    phi = odeint(actual, phi_0, tm)

    # plot results
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(tm*60, phi[:, :])
    plt.ylabel('phi')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.show()

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  GEKKO model
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.time = tm

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # initialize state variables: phi_hat
    # ref: https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/estimate_hiv.zip
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    phi_hat = [m.CV(value=phi_0[i]) for i in range(ngrid)]  # initialize phi_hat; variable to match with measurement

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # parameters (/control parameters to be optimized while minimizing the cost function in GEKKO)
    # ref: http://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicEstimation
    # ref: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective
    # def model
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #  Manually enter guesses for parameters
    Dhat0 = 5000*np.ones(ngrid-1)
    Dhat = [m.MV(value=Dhat0[i]) for i in range(0, ngrid-1)]
    for i in range(ngrid-1):
        Dhat[i].STATUS = 1  # Allow optimizer to fit these values
        # Dhat[i].LOWER = 0

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # differential equations
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    M, MT = get_mmt()
    A = MT @ np.diag(Dhat) @ M
    A = A[1:ngrid - 1]

    # first node
    m.Equation(phi_hat[0].dt() == 0)
    # interior nodes

    int_value = -A @ phi_hat  # function value at interior nodes
    m.Equations(phi_hat[i].dt() == int_value[i] for i in range(0, ngrid-2))

    # terminal node
    m.Equation(phi_hat[ngrid-1].dt() == Dhat[end] * 2 * (phi_hat[end-1] - phi_hat[end]))

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # simulation
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    m.options.IMODE = 5  # simultaneous dynamic estimation
    m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
    m.options.EV_TYPE = 2  # squared-error :minimize model prediction to measurement

    for i in range(ngrid):
        phi_hat[i].FSTATUS = 1  # fit to measurement phi obtained from 'def actual'
        phi_hat[i].STATUS = 1  # build objective function to match measurement and prediction
        phi_hat[i].value = phi[:, i]

    m.solve()
    pprint(Dhat)
```

In short, I'd like to ask for inputs on how to set up the `m.Obj`, `m.CV`, and `m.FV` in GEKKO to solve this problem.

EDIT:
 `m.CV`, and `m.FV`  have been updated in the code. I'd like to request for help with setting up the objective function alone.

Comment: There is a similar question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028331/defining-control-variables-and-objective-function-in-gekko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good first step with any parameter estimation problem is to solve it in simulation to verify that you can get a good solution and that the parameters have an effect on the objective. You can first simulate with `m.options.IMODE=7`.

Once you have an initial solution, you can set your objective function with:

```py
for i in range(n):
    m.Minimize((phi[i]-phi_hat[i])**2)
```

You can have as many `Minimize` or `Maximize` statements as you need. Gekko adds all of them together to create a scalar objective value.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in objective function that comes with a `CV object` with `m.options.EV_TYPE=2` to set a squared objective. You just need to give it values such as:

```py
phi = m.Array(m.CV,n)
for i in range(n):
    phi[i].value = phi_hat[i]
    phi[i].FSTATUS = 1
```

The length of `phi_hat[i]` must be consistent with the number of time steps that you have defined with `m.time`. I recommend tutorials at https://apmonitor.com/do for more information on setting up your problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. `phi = m.Array(m.CV,n) = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)` when n=10. Is it correct to understand that the value of `phi` is initilaized to zeros in this step. Could you please explain how to initialize it to a different value other than zeros? Doing , `phi = [m.CV(value=phi_0[i]) for i in range(n)]` initializes `phi ` as a list.

Comment: You could do the following: `[phi[i].value=phi_0[i] for i in range(n)]`. This would only change the value and not redefine `phi`.